# HTML Print - Window.print() not printing input type="text" value

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have this on my html layout (there is a print link up there - i failed to include on the screenshot)

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>
```

But after I click PRINT, the value inside the textbox is not printed.. see 2nd photo.
pls help :) 
[image: HTML Layout]

[image: Print OUTPUT]

Comment: I have read that before i posted this question, I haven't found any answer there that could work for me :(

Comment: Can you add your html please. It will help to resolve issue. css and javascript as well if used.